# Angular2, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Im learning Angular2 framework, and just stuck in middle. Goal - simple app that loading view from desired component (Home).

Here is what i have:

app/app.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

app/app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule }    from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }         from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent }        from './home/home.component';
import { DemoService }          from './services/demo.service';
import { routing }              from './app.routing';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    DemoService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

app/app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DemoService} from './services/demo.service';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {routing,
         appRoutingProviders} from './app.routing';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: require('./app.component.html'),
  providers: [DemoService]
})

export class AppComponent {}
```

/app/app.component.html

```
<div>AppComponent</div>
```

../index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
  </body>
</html>
```

app/home/home.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DemoService} from '../services/demo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  template: require('./home.component.html')
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string = 'Home Page';
  body:  string = 'This is the about home body';
  message: string;

  constructor(private _stateService: DemoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.message = this._stateService.getMessage();
  }

  updateMessage(m: string): void {
    this._stateService.setMessage(m);
  }
}
```

app/app.routing.ts

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { HomeComponent }      from './home/home.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [

];

export const routing: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

app/home/home.component.html

```
<div>HomeComponent</div>
```

As its coming from the components definitions, i have respective DemoSevice, that does nothin at the moment. Having app started i get "Loading..." and nothing else changes.

Could you please suggest me correct path?

Comment: Could you check browser console?

Comment: do you get any error? look at console, Also do you sure your `./app.component.html` has `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`?

Comment: first remove `providers: [DemoService]` from `app/app.component.ts`. Then check browser console and let us know about error(s).

Comment: @micronyks, removed providers declaration. Console has nothing - empty.

Comment: @PankajParkar, not sure about router-outler, why do i need it? i guess i dont have it. Where is it supposed to be?

Comment: @could you add `app.component.html` code?

Comment: @PankajParkar, done. Basically i have nothing there... I thought it would be atleast loaded and sent to output.

Comment: then try to remove `routing` from `imports` and `homeComponent` from `declarations` and remove `router-outlet` as well. Then see if `AppComponnent` gets loaded at least or not.

Comment: @micronyks, done. and still same. "Loading..." text is not replaced with AppComponent text. Is my index.html is correct?

Comment: Then this way it is hard to find out the problem. You must crate a plunker for the same now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `router-outlet` directive placed inside your `app.component.html`. The reason behind adding that directive is, it will keep track browser URL & Angular router will load appropriate `Component` inside `router-outlet` directive

**/app/app.component.html**

```
<div>AppComponent</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Additionally you have to put various script file related to angular2 on index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.6.17?main=browser"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata@0.1.3"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.27/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>
</body>
```

Comment: Added, no change. Same "loading..." and nothin else.

Comment: @Pankaj it should be `<app>Loading...</app>`. else OP can check the scripting part.

Comment: @Pankaj, once added <header> scripes, i get 404 in console - http://localhost:3000/app/main.js. But i dont have main.ts file anywhere...

Comment: One more thing I think OP uses webpack  if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @micronyks thanks for heads up, I did mistake there, Thanks :) he must have messed up with the script including part

Comment: @micronyks how are you sure about webpack? I guess error wasn't happening because he haven't included any angular2 script on page.

Comment: @ArkadyB, are you using Webpack as a module loader?

Comment: @micronyks, not sure. I was following the angular started and thought to modify it with different routes and calling my backend services. I have done everythin it was written in the QuickStarts. Therefore im doing npm install and then start.. How could i be sure its Webpack or not?

Comment: There is only one way to come up with plunker or wait for somebody else to respond.

Comment: Could you upddate questions with what you have in index.html

Comment: @ArkadyB- Oh wait... not sure but change `template: require('./app.component.html')` to `templateUrl:'app/app.component.html'`

Comment: @micronyks, changing to URL worked for me. Thanks! + Needed to do some tweaks with base url and so on, but after all ITS ALIVE! The most awful thing about Angular 2 is all around examples use different RC version and therefore code is different...

Comment: @PankajParkar, thank you! router-outlet did was part of the problem too.

Comment: @ArkadyB Glad to know that I helped, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to change `template: require('./app.component.html')` to `templateUrl:'app/app.component.html'`.

2)try to change it to

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo:'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];
```

3) **app/app.componet.html**

```
<div>AppComponent</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>  //<----added here..
```

Comment: Tried this one with no luck. AppComponent does not seem to get loaded

Comment: then try to remove `routing` from `imports` and `homeComponent` from `declarations` and remove `router-outlet` as well. Then see if `AppComponnent` gets loaded at least or not.